# Take a column list and break into multiple comma delimited rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The code below takes the list in Column A and turns the entire column into a comma delimited list in cell B1.  Instead, I want to be able to control the range in Column A and control which cell the results go to. For example, I want to put A1:A4 in B1 and then A5:A8 in B2.  Anyone know how to code this.  Thanks

```
Sub test()
    Range("B1") = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value), ",")
End Sub
```

I want the results to look like the second group in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be VBA because this can be done in a formula without code.

Comment: Text Join isn't working in my version for some reason.

Comment: You'd really want to try and work that out, not build something custom I'd say.

Comment: You're trying to create a user defined function for use on a worksheet? Or would you be calling this procedure from a userform or command button, or from within the IDE?

Comment: What version of excel?  What you're asking is a little bit ambiguous though - what are the rules for what should be placed where?  Anything can be done, but your example is not very detailed - eg B1 has four items but B2 has five: I would have expected five then four (last cell has "leftover" items)

Comment: Tim, I just wanted it placed where I have it in the picture. I want to be able to say I want Rows A1:A4 joined in Cell B1 and Rows A5:A9 joined in Cell B2.

Comment: So `Range("B1") = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A4").Value), ","): 
    Range("B2") = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A5:A8").Value), ",")` ?

Comment: Tim, that works great, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with `TextJoin` and it's definitely not working (I'd be pushing to get it working rather than working around it) then this will work for you, it's the same sort of concept.

```
Public Function MyTextJoin(ByVal strDelimiter As String, ByVal bIgnoreGaps As Boolean, ByVal rngValues As Range) As String
    Dim objCell As Range, strValue As String, bAddValue As Boolean
    
    For Each objCell In rngValues
        bAddValue = False
        strValue = objCell.Text
            
        If strValue <> "" Then
            bAddValue = True
        Else
            If Not bIgnoreGaps Then bAddValue = True
        End If
        
        If bAddValue Then MyTextJoin = MyTextJoin & strDelimiter & strValue
    Next
    
    If Left(MyTextJoin, 1) = "," Then MyTextJoin = Mid(MyTextJoin, 2)
End Function
```

**FYI** - `TextJoin` is only available in later versions of Excel so if the formula doesn't exist at all, that'll be why.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c